# Manipulate size on a single-axis ordiplot graph

Tags: r, fonts, vegan

I am drawing a single axis graph for my ordinations data using ordiplot function from Vegan package
the code is as  follows:

```
ordiplot(data, choices = 1)
```

I am interested in the first axis only, and what i get is this:

[image: graph].

my problem is that I am not able to make the font larger. I tried "cex", "cex.lab", "cex.main", "cex.axis"  and nothing works.
this generic font size is far to small for my publication - I'd appreciate some input from more experienced R coders.

(maybe there are some other, better than ordiplot, function that would make a decent single-axis graph - suggestions are welcome)

Comment: please add a little data to play with, preferably using `dput()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little infelicity in the implementation of `ordiplot()` when used with a single axis: `cex` is an argument to `ordiplot()` yet this doesn't get passed on to `linestack()`, which does the actual plotting in this case. Only additional arguments passed via `...` get passed to the `linestack()` call.

You can regain some control by using `linestack()` directly:

```r
linestack(scores(data, choices = 1, display = "sites"),
          cex = 1.1, col = "blue")
linestack(scores(data, choices = 1, display = "species"),
          cex = 0.8, col = "red", side = "left")
```

See `?linestack` for more details.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: No worries; I'll fix the infelicity in `ordiplot()` so that supplying `cex` is passed along to `linestack()`, but it might take a while to get out to CRAN.